# International Transit at Munich Airport

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, muc

If you need to transit between terminal 1 & terminal 2 in Munich airport (international transit from Manchester to Muscat), do you need to go out the immigration area (passport control)?

If so, do you need a Schengen visa for transit between the terminals?

Comment: We'd need to know your country of citizenship to know whether you'd need a visa at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk Not a dupe, as the linked Q says it depends on whether you need to enter Schengen. This Q specifically asks whether OP does need to enter Schengen

Answer (score 3):

As Henning Makholm says, there is a transfer bus between the terminals. One half of the bus is for passengers in the Schengen sector, the other half for passengers in the non-Schengen sector. The halves are blocked off from each other by a glass wall, and at each stop (which is located either in the Schengen or non-Schengen sector), only the doors in the "correct" half of the bus will open.

So you don't need to enter Germany, and, unless holding a nationality requiring an airport transit visa, you don't need a visa.

This is provided the trip is in a **single booking**. With separate bookings, if you have checked luggage you need to enter Germany to collect it, and thus need a short-stay (type C) Schengen visa. And even with only hand luggage, ground staff in the UK will usually treat Germany as your final destination, and deny you boarding without a short-stay Schengen visa.

Answer (score 1):

There's a non-Schengen transfer bus between the terminals, leaving every 15 minutes from gates H/C08.

https://www.munich-airport.com/_b/0000000000000001770851bb5901fc90/basis-route-neu-200317.pdf

So you don't need to enter Schengen.

Comment: The person may still need a visa though.